# when I close elasticsearch master node,is this condition right?

Tags: elasticsearch

My environment:

elasticsearch-7.4.2  node-1,node-2(two nodes,and node-2 is the master node)

When I closed the node-2 ,which is the master node, the node-1 begin to find the master node and show like this:

> [node-1] master not discovered or elected yet, an election requires a
>   node with id [eUfWAIhSQzCRcisWz-DiFg], have discovered
>   [{node-1}{WbYI8RHITU2aJYMMoD-ZXw}{0iKKLbdeQ3mmWNKo7iKkOg}{192.168.1.41}{192.168.1.41:9300}{dim}{rack=r1,
>   xpack.installed=true}] which is not a quorum; discovery will continue
>   using [192.168.1.42:9300] from hosts providers and
>   [{node-1}{WbYI8RHITU2aJYMMoD-ZXw}{0iKKLbdeQ3mmWNKo7iKkOg}{192.168.1.41}{192.168.1.41:9300}{dim}{rack=r1,
>   xpack.installed=true}] from last-known cluster state; node term 5,
>   last-accepted version 245 in term 5

I just want to know the reason to avoiding Cerebral fissure or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the case of a cluster with three nodes, then:
master_nodes: 2
A best practice to determine this number is to use the following formula to decide this number: N/2 + 1. N is the number of master eligible nodes in the cluster

Comment: so,your mean is that  I should add a external node to be my master node ?  And  when I closed one of the master node , this situation is not appear ,right?